# Get ClassOfDevice from BluetoothDevice

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth

After creating device with `var device = await BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(classicAddress)` its ClassOfDevice properties are empty `ClassOfDevice.MinorClass` and `ClassOfDevice.MajorClass` are equal to 0.

To get device with that information supplied I need to call `DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher` or `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync`, but both of these methods take long time to complete (i think there is 30s timeout), even with selector targeting single bluetooth address. Is there way to get this device metadata without performing full scan?

Comment: Use classic Bluetooth API instead. Is faster.

Comment: What classic BT Api you have in mind? Windows.Devices.Bluetooth/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm does not have anything to enumerate devices.

Comment: This one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-start-page